# Why is C program for 2D array list making last row into NULL character ^@?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

**I used vim to write it, if that makes a difference** I am reformatting a char array (created by loading chars from a basic text file)by loading into a 2D char array, row by row, in C. The 'key' value is the number of chars per row, and 'length' is the number of chars in the original array. I then print the 2D array, Column by column, as a string. The function works as it should, however, the final column of the 2D array is always fully replaced by null characters. I have tried pre-filling the original array with spaces before adding the text file chars, as well as playing around with my for loop parameters. Does anyone know what is causing this error?
For example, if my original array is "Hello, you" with a key 3, my 2D output will be [He^@], [lo^@], [ y^@], [u  ].  Thank you!

```
char inputData[500];

void encrypt(int key, int length){

        char matrix[500][500];
        int row;
        int coln;
        int num_rows;
        int blanks;

        if ((key%length) == 0) {
                num_rows = length/key;
                blanks = 0;
        }
        if ((key%length) != 0) {
                num_rows = (length/key)+1;
                blanks = 1;
        }

        for (row = 0; row <= num_rows; row++){
                coln = 0;
                for (coln = 0; coln < key; coln++){
                        int insert_index = (row*key) + coln;
                        char insert = inputData[insert_index];
                        matrix[row][coln] = insert;
                }
        }

        if (blanks == 1) {
                int row = (length/key);
                int coln_num = (length%key);
                for ( coln = coln_num; coln < key; coln ++){
                        matrix[row][coln] = ' ';
                }

        }

        for ( coln = 0; coln < key; coln++ ){
                row = 0;
                for ( row = 0; row < num_rows; row++){
                        char show = matrix[row][coln];
                        printf("%c", show);
                }
        }
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

        int key = atoi(argv[2]);

        int length = atoi(argv[3]);

        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
                inputData[i]=' ';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
                char chars = getc(stdin);
                inputData[i]=chars;
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0) {
                encrypt(key, length);
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0) {
                decrypt(key, length);
        }

}
```

Comment: You're storing `length + 1` characters into the array:  `0` through `length`, rather than the more typical `0` through `length-1`.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @TomKarzes I have tried both ways; same result

Comment: I'm not saying that's the only problem, but it looks like it could be contributing to it.

Comment: Can't reproduce, seems to work fine: https://godbolt.org/z/z6nd3c8q8

Answer (score 1):

SO, the error was coming from another function, decrypt, that I did not show , because I thought it had no bearing. The length value being fed into decrypt was different that that being fed into encrypt, as encrypt adds spaces to fill in the matrix. As you can see in main, I did not change the length of inputData when running it to decrypt.